# Dynamically change one of f-string variables

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

Is there a way to dynamically change/substitute one of f-string variables?
Let's say I have format as follows:

```py
expected = f'{var} {self.some_evaluation_1(var)} {self.some_evaluation_2(var)}'
```

Then I have test case with multiple assertions:

```py
var1='some value 1'
var2='some value 2'
var3='some value 3'

var=var1
self.assertEqual('some great value1', expected)
var=var2
self.assertEqual('some great value2', expected)
var=var3
self.assertEqual('some great value3', expected)
```

Is there a way to make f-string use my variable instead of defined in initial format?

```py
# Let's say something like this? It's just a concept I know it doesn't work.
self.assertEqual('some great value1', expected % var1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the result of an f-string expression is an *immutable* string.  Similar to:

```
y = 'abc'
x = y + 'def' # result of expression is immutable string.
y = 'ghi'
print(x)  # would you expect 'ghidef'? No...
```

If you want it to change, use `format` instead of f-strings to re-evaluate `expected`:

```
expected = 'test{}' # NOT an f-string
var = 1
assert expected.format(var) == 'test1'
var = 2
assert expected.format(var) == 'test2'
```

If you have named variables as in your example, you can use:

```
expected = 'test{var}'
assert expected.format(var=1) == 'test1'
```

or pass `locals()` as a dictionary of arguments using keyword expansion (**):

```
expected = 'test{a}{b}'
a = 1
b = 2
assert expected.format(**locals()) == 'test12'
```